# BootStrap Carousel Slide Animation flicker

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In the demo of the carousel on Bootstrap, the slides are connected and clearly move "together", when I go next/prev slide, the current slide can be seen transitioning away, while the new slide transitions in.

However, when I copy pasted the sample code, my transitions are very choppy, instead of the 1st picture transitioning away, it simply disappears and the next slide transitions in, leaving this blank white space on the page everytime the carousel transitions.

How come its doing this and how do I fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many issues at play here. But to show you a fully working copy to reference against, here is a JSfiddle of the carousel

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fatchild/j310af6n/13/

Things I would check...

1. I have included all the relevant libraries for bootstrap to work. (see the JSFiddle)
2. Check that the system choppy-ness isn't down to a slow system. Move your code onto something like JSFiddle and compare to mine.
3. Shake your computer whilst screaming.

Comment: Adding in the proper libraries from your JSFiddle seems to have done the trick, however I have some custom CSS to move the caption and make the next/prev icons more visible against the image background, and it seems this is causing my slides to have, almost 1 whole slide worth of white space, inbetween my actual slides. So basically the animation works better now, but there is crazy amount of white space. And I've already tired option 3 maybe 5 times last week.

Comment: not sure what happened, but while I was fiddling around with some other stuff, the white space problem has been fixed...

Comment: Interesting! Maybe try backtracking and see what you changed that fixed it, I would be interested to know. p.s. probably wasn't the computer shaking ;)

Comment: After trying to revert the few things that came to my mind, and hard reloading the page with empty cache, it doesn't look like the enormous white space is coming back. Here are some speculations as to what might have caused it:

1 - During the phase where it occured, I may not have hard reloaded/ the page when testing
2 - I wrapped the whole page in a `<div class="container-fluid">` but when I tried removing this and hard reloading it also didnt seem to bring back the white space
3 - I cleaned up some more useless script sourcing (by reloading the page with some links commented out)

Comment: 1 and 3 seem the most likely to me. But at least it is fixed now. Nice!